# connect not listening to the state update in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using React and Redux in my application. I wanted to show `confirmationDialog` in my app and I want it in such a way that an action is fired from some component, it updates my `redux` state and then the `confirmationDialog` would listen to that state and open itself up. The code of `confirmationDialog` is :

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import Dialog from 'material-ui/Dialog';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import {hideConfirmationDialog} from '../../../actions/globalActions';
import {getConfirmationDialogState} from '../../../selectors/globalSelectors';

/**
 * A modal dialog can only be closed by selecting one of the actions.
 */
class DialogBox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const props = this.props,
      actions = [
        <RaisedButton
          label={props.cancelLabel}
          secondary
          onClick={props.onCancel}
        />,
        <RaisedButton
          label={props.submitLabel}
          primary
          onClick={props.onSubmit}
          className="ml-4"
        />,
      ];

    return (
      <Dialog
        title={props.title}
        actions={actions}
        modal
        autoScrollBodyContent={props.autoScrollBodyContent}
        open={props.show}
      >
        {props.message || props.children}
      </Dialog>
    );
  }
}

DialogBox.propTypes = {
  onCancel: PropTypes.func,
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func,
  show: PropTypes.bool,
  submitLabel: PropTypes.string,
  cancelLabel: PropTypes.string,
  autoScrollBodyContent: PropTypes.bool,
};

DialogBox.defaultProps = {
  submitLabel: __('Submit'),
  cancelLabel: __('Cancel'),
  autoScrollBodyContent: true,
};

const ConnectedConfirmationDialog = connect(getConfirmationDialogState, { hideConfirmationDialog })(DialogBox);

export default ConnectedConfirmationDialog;

export {DialogBox};
```

Here `getConfirmationDialogState` is a selector to get the confirmation dialog state from my reducer.

I'd call my confirmation dialog as :

```
showDialog({
            title: 'Delete Entities',
            message: 'Delete selected entities',
            onSubmit: _.noop,
            onCancel: _.noop,
          });
```

The `showDialog` function is defined in a `util` which would `dispatch` and action such that:

```
const buildConfirmationDialogAction = ({ title, message, onSubmit, onCancel }) => (
  Store.dispatch(showConfirmationDialog({
    onSubmit,
    title,
    onCancel,
    message,
  }))
);

export const showDialog = params => buildConfirmationDialogAction(params);
```

The corresponding action would update the state. the state is getting updated but the `getConfirmationDialog` in my component is not getting called and show the component is not getting re-rendered. I've no clue now why connect is not listening to `mapStateToProps`.

Comment: please share the code of `getConfirmationDialogState`

Comment: It was a selector and it was fine. Also, I Have answered my question

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't rendered the confirmation dialog in my `app` file. As the component wasn't rendered, it wouldn't listen to the state updation. So, in the starting file, I did :

```
 render() {
    const that = this,
      props = that.props,
      alert = props.alert || {};

    return (
      <div className="h-100">
        <DocumentTitle title={DOORCERY_TITLE}>
          <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={doorceryTheme}>
            <div className="h-100">
              <ConfirmationDialog
                show={false}
              />
              {props.children}
            </div>
          </MuiThemeProvider>
        </DocumentTitle>
      </div>
    );
  }
```